# Is there a way to check a variable that exists in a different script than the original one?

Tags: python

I'm trying to check if a variable, which was previously set to true in `2.py` in `1.py`, as `1.py` is only supposed to continue if the variable is true.

**2.py**

```
import os

completed = false

#some stuff here

completed = true
```

**1.py**

```
import 2 

if completed == true
   #do things
```

however I get a syntax error at

```
if completed == true
```

Comment: Incidentally `if completed == True` isn't necessary. `if completed` is enough. In case you really want `completed` to be a `bool`, you will need `if completed is True`, i.e. `1 == True` but `1` isn't `True`. Actually not the same address memory.

Comment: `if completed == True:` Use `True` Capital T

Comment: python circular problem?

Comment: First of all true and false values in Python are defined as **True** or **False**. Secondly, in order to access the completed value from 1.py into 2.py you need to call it as **2.completed** or modify your import statement to **from 2 import completed** to call it as you do in your code.

Comment: If it's a constant you can try `if 2.completed` or try to inport it directly `from 2 import completed`

Comment: @omnibus Darius please accept the answer that helped you solve your problem by clicking on the tick sign beside it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.py

```
import os

completed = False

#some stuff here

completed = True
```

2.py:

```
import 2

if 2.completed:
    print("Gotcha!")
   #do things
```

and then:

```
py -m 2.py
```

OUTPUT:

```
Gotcha!
```

Answer (score 1):

use `2.completed` with `import 2` or `completed` with `from 2 import completed`. If you want more information search for `python namespaces`.

Also, if it wasn't obvious already, don't use 2 as a module name.